# Normal subgroup $N$, subgroup $U$, then $UN/N = U/N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $N \unlhd G$ a normal subgroup, $U \le G$ some subgroup. Then I guess $U / N$ is always some group, and moreover $U / N = UN / N$, because $UN / N = \{ unN : u \in U, n \in N \} = \{ uN : u \in U \}$ by $unN = uN$ for $n \in N$.

Is this right? I am wondering because nowhere I find such an statement that $U / N = UN / N$, moreover, the second isomorphism theorem states something weaker, namely $U / (U\cap N) \cong UN/N$. So I guess such an statement would be interesting, and also writing $U/N$ instead of $UN/N$ seems to be more clearly to me, or have I overlooked something?

Comment: I personally agree, but I have found many more (published) people prefer $UN/N$ to $U/N$. This is perhaps because the subgroups of $G/N$ are exactly $H/N$ where $N \leq H \leq G$, and $H/N$ is normal in $G/N$ iff $H$ is normal in $G$ in that case. If you use notation like $U/N$ then we no longer have $U/N$ is normal in $G/N$ iff $U$ is normal in $G$ (it has to be changed to "iff $UN$ is normal in $G$").

Comment: The quotient group is defined as a set "[..] We define the set G/N to be the set of all left cosets of N in G, i.e., G/N = { aN : a in G }" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group). But actually your comment suggests that the notation is more than just a set, it is defined relative to this correspondence. Seems quite odd, an implicit aggreement among group theorists nowhere explicitly states in the initial definitions in an otherwise quite explicit science. But now I know, thank you for your answer!

Comment: In the wikipedia article, $N$ is assumed to be a (normal) subgroup of $G$. In particular, it does not define the notation $U/N$ when $N$ is not a subgroup of $U$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That seems to be the point!

Comment: How do you define U/N? I know how to define the quotient G/H as a group precisely when H is a normal subgroup of G. So, when looking at U/N, I tend to think N is a normal subgroup of U.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I have always understood this, it is completely possible and common for $N$ to not be contained in $U$ at all.  So, it would not make sense to mod out by $N$.  But, taking $UN$ first, will be the smallest subgroup that contains both $U$ and $N$, which then gives us what we need to make sense of the quotient.

Moreover, the second Isomorphism theorem gives us that $UN/N \cong U/(U\cap N)$.